# How to find logical length of the file in bytes in C#

Tags: c++, file, c#-4.0, system.io.fileinfo, cfile

I am trying to re-write a part of my application from ATL/COM(C++) to WPF, C#. In the older application they use

```
m_inputFile = new CFile(fileName,CFile::modeRead);
DWORD fileLength= (DWORD) m_inputFile->GetLength();
```

But when I use FileInfo.Length in C# application, this gives incorrect value. What is the correct way to implement logical length of file in C#? Any advise is greatly appreciated.

Comment: FileInfo.Length works. Something else is going on.

Comment: If you are opening the file in text mode and reading the contents **and** the file contains Windows line-endings the line endings will be converted from two bytes to one. This will cause the number of bytes read to be different than the value returned by a call to `FileInfo.Length`.

Comment: how is the fileLength value being used?

Comment: I only have 128 bits in my file and FileInfo.Length returns 134 as the length. This is how fileLength value is used as follows: this.nBlocks = (int)Math.Round((double)(this.fileLength) / 16);